# How to avoid multiple subquery as expression (SQL optimization)

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have two tables 
TABLE A

```
user_id             external_party_id
  1                        6
```

TABLE B

```
user_id    activated    user_mode         sale_mode
  1          false      'Customer'         'Web'          
  1          true       'Customer'         'Local'        
  1          true       'Partner'          'Web'         
  1          true       'Partner'          'Local'
```

RESULT

```
user_id   external_party_id   customer_web   customer_local  partner_web   partner_local
  1         6                   false          true        true             true
  2         7                   false          false        true             false
```

Right now I have this following kind of query

```
SELECT
  u.*,
  (SELECT activated
   FROM TABLE_B
   WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND user_mode = 'Customer' AND sale_mode = 'Web'
  ) AS customer_web,
  (SELECT activated
   FROM TABLE_B
   WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND user_mode = 'Customer' AND sale_mode = 'Local'
  ) AS customer_local,
  (SELECT activated
   FROM TABLE_B
   WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND user_mode = 'Partner' AND sale_mode = 'Web'
  ) AS partner_web,
  (SELECT activated
   FROM TABLE_B
   WHERE user_id = u.user_id AND user_mode = 'Partner' AND sale_mode = 'Local'
  ) AS partner_local,
FROM TABLE_A AS u;
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to achieve this. Does this query try querying to TABLE_B four times to populate each column value?

Comment: It's a pivot problem: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: @MarkusWinand thanks I will definitely read up on that. Just curious whether this way is really inefficient or it just involves more code?

Comment: accessing the table only once will be faster. Just make sure to add a global `where` clause that is as restrictive as possible (`WHERE user_mode IN ('Partner', 'Customer') AND sale_mode('Web', 'Local')`. Depending on your data, adding an index might help. In PostgreSQL, you could even use a partial index for that: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/partial-and-filtered-indexes

Comment: Does using WITH statement helps me to reduce query in this case?

Comment: I don't see a reason to use `with` here. I'd go for  a pivot query. Unlike [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47092418/312881) I'd do the pivot part in a subquery before joining it to the other table.

Answer (score 0):

use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,u.external_party_id,
  MAX (CASE WHEN user_mode = 'Customer' AND sale_mode = 'Web' THEN activated END) AS customer_web,
  MAX (CASE WHEN user_mode = 'Customer' AND sale_mode = 'Local' THEN activated END) AS customer_local,
  MAX (CASE WHEN user_mode = 'Partner' AND sale_mode = 'Web' THEN activated END) AS partner_web,
  MAX (CASE WHEN user_mode = 'Partner' AND sale_mode = 'Local' THEN activated END) AS partner_local
FROM TABLE_A AS u
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON b.user_id = u.user_id
GROUP BY u.user_id,u.external_party_id
```

Comment: Hi what does MAX do in this case?

Comment: @Zanko since `user_mode` and `sale_mode` are not part of the `GROUP BY` they have to be in the aggregate function. You may use `MIN` as well since it is selecting from a set of values, where all are `NULL` and just one has value  (the one satisfying the condition).

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same format, but you can rephrase this using a direct left join:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.activated,
    b.user_mode,
    b.sales_mode
FROM TABLE_A AS a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B AS b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND
       user_mode IN ('Customer', 'Partner') AND
       sale_mode IN ('Web', 'Local');
```